# Form will Not Show Hover CSS on Submit Button

Tags: css

http://seniorbenefitsnevada.com/

I have a form with the following Code:

```
<div class="shoponline">
                        <form action="#" method="post">

                            <!-- Select plan -->

                <div class="sp">



                                <!--<select name="select-plan" class="styled-select"> 

                                  <option>(select a plan)</option>

                                  <option>Medicare plans</option>

                                  <option>Supplemental plans</option>

                                  <option>Life insurance</option>

                                </select>-->

                <input type="text" name="select-plan" id="select-plan" size="5" maxlength="5" placeholder="enter zip code" onfocus="this.placeholder = ''" onblur="this.placeholder = 'Enter Zip Code'">

                </div>

                             <!-- Select Plan END -->

                            <input type="submit" value="Go">


                        </form>
</div>
```

The following CSS is being used to change the gradient of the CSS.

```
.shoponline input[type="submit"]:hover {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffb847 0%,#ffb847 100%) !important;
}
```

However, the CSS isn't even being recognized. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What makes you think it's not being recognized? http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/z7v7L/

Comment: Works [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/5hNy2/). You probably need some vendors/prefixes on the linear-gradients for support.

Comment: I see nothing happening on the hover.

Comment: @Ken What browser are you using..?

Comment: @ken what browser are you using?

Comment: http://seniorbenefitsnevada.com/

Comment: I see it adding color...I don't see anything happening on the hover though.

Comment: @Ken I don't see any `:hover` rule like that in your website's CSS

Comment: http://seniorbenefitsnevada.com/?sccss=1&ver=3.7.1

Comment: Your CSS has encoded quotes -- that is, change `[type=&quot;submit&quot;]` to `[type="submit"]`